# RNFetchBlob blob not being removed after close()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I am uploading an image from the local (ios) filesystem to Firebase using RNFetchBlob

Although my image is being deleted, my blob is remaining in the filesystem after closing it.
I tried unlinking the blob but it still remains

```
function createBlob(uri, mediaType) {
  const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob; 
  const typePrefix = isImage(mediaType) ? 'image' : 'video';  
  window.Blob = Blob;
  window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;  

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const uid = guid();
    const mediaRef = firebase.storage().ref('users').child(`${uid}.${mediaType}`);
    let uploadBlob = null;

    Blob.build(uri, { type: `${typePrefix}/${mediaType}` })
    .then((blob) => {
      uploadBlob = blob;
      return mediaRef.put(blob, { type: `${typePrefix}/${mediaType}` });
    })
    .then((response) => {
      uploadBlob.close();

      resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

This is how it looks in my simulator folder after closing the blob

[image]

After the `createBlob` I am deleting the file from local storage using `RNFetchBlob.fs.unlink(path)`

Comment: Can you show how you're attempting to unlink the file? [The docs](https://libraries.io/github/ReactNativeSorurce/react-native-fetch-blob#cache-file-management) explain a couple of possible methods.

Comment: @TPorter Thanks. I think there's only one way unless you use a session

Comment: Why are u wrapping Blob.build with a new Promise? You could just return the promise - Blob.build. Is uploadBlob.close an async operation? In that case, you probably have to wait for it before attempting to unlink.

Comment: @vijayst You're right. uploadBlob.close is async and returns a promise. But even after waiting for the close to unlink, the blob is not being removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're `close()` is working because the `uploadBlob` variable was created in the previous closure, but not passed on to the next `.then` block. I'm thinking this might work...

```
Blob.build(uri, { type: `${typePrefix}/${mediaType}` })
.then((blob) => {
  uploadBlob = blob;
  return ({
     response: mediaRef.put(blob, { type: `${typePrefix}/${mediaType}` }),
     blob: uploadBlob
})
.then(({response, blob}) => {
  blob.close();

  resolve(response);
})
```

Comment: That does indeed remove the blob, but fails with error "Can't retrieve the file from the path."

Comment: Great! I guess that's a different problem. What line is that error occurring on?

Comment: That error was app specific. You did get to the root of the problem though. Why does uploadBlob need to be passed in as a object parameter to the returned promise?

Comment: each `.then()` block is block scoped, so you either need to set the variable on the global scope so that all `then()'s` have access, or pass it along explicitly.